# django csrf error during file upload in admin

Tags: django, admin

I have a strange behaviour of the django admin (django 1.11) - on both development and production: When I upload files that are larger than about 1.5 MB I get a csrf verification error. Files smaller than that limit I can upload without any trouble.

There is nothing special in the model and admin:

```
class Literatur(models.Model):
    name= models.CharField(max_length=80)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to="docs/",null=True, blank=True)
```

Admin.py

```
admin.site.register(Literatur)
```

Where can I look to resolve this issue?

Comment: add your function which is responsible for file upload. And do you set value in `MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE` in `settings.py`?

Comment: The upload is done by the django admin. I have not set any MAX_UPLOAD_SIZE.

Comment: set in bigger amount. The value will be in bytes.

Comment: Is this a real setting - I could not find anything in the docs of django 1.11? And also tried it but it was ignored. However, if I set and increase the FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE it works. But this is more a work around than a real solution.